# localhost 3000 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, macos, reactjs, localhost

http://localhost:3000

Somehow I can't connect to above address but my app is accessible using

http://192.168.0.25:3000

I'm running this boilerplate. https://github.com/notrab/create-react-app-redux

I don't know what is wrong and this is my first time having this issue.

Comment: Does http://127.0.0.1:3000 work?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: try different browsers

Comment: It sounds like you're developing your react application on a different machine, and not the machine you're using. I just did the same thing. Or you have some firewall rules setup to block it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to connect to [localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000) your server should use this ip address: [127.0.0.1:3000](http://127.0.0.1:3000).

Comment: Why don't you add suggestions as a comment to the question before answering? it would be safer to avoid wrong answers or getting down-voted.